# Deleting Parts of Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, recursion, tree, search-tree

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Return the root of a binary search tree t modified to contain only values <= k. (Using the normal BST class where we have an item,left and right)

```
def prune(t,k):
    if not t:
        return None
    if k < t.item
        while t.item > k:
            t = t.left
    return t
```

I think I am doing it completely wrong.. Maybe there is some easy recursive way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
def prune(t, k):
    if t is None or t.item > k:
        return None
    t.right = prune(t.right, k)
    return t
```

This is recursive, and will "prune" when it reaches any `None` node or node larger than `k`. As this is a BST, `t.item <= k` means all nodes in `t.left` will be too, so we can ignore them.

Comment: that wont work, since if I prune a node smaller that is part of the left subtree, the function will do nothing. e.g BTNode(7, BTNode(4, BTNode(3, None, None), None), BTNode(10, None, None)) , if I pick 5, it will remain unchanged since the value is not in the right subtree.

Comment: @Mac if you pick `k=5` you won't get anything back, as `7 > 5`! Have you actually tried it out?